# How to identify and remove all the special characters from the data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| col1 |
| --- |
| Ntwk Lane 0 cannot on high operational\n |
| TX_PWR ALARM. TX_PWR also fluctuates over time (found Tx power dropped to -2dBm also raises TX_PWR_LO_ALRM |
| module report ASIC_PLL_REF_CLK_FREQ_ERR(20008=0x800000) and HOST_REF_PLL_2(20014=0x2) |

I want to remove all the special characters from the column how to do that. I need only alphabets rest I need to remove

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression:

```
import re
df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]').sub('', x))
```

As suggested by @[9769953](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9769953/9769953)

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.replace('[^a-zA-Z]', '', regex=True)
```

is also a much cleaner approach. Same performance, but cleaner.

Comment: `.str.replace()` can take a regular expression. That probably looks clearer, and might be faster as well.

Comment: Thanks. I Forgot that this exists too. But I measured it, takes the same time.

Comment: I guess the regex takes the majority of the computational time involved, so then any differences won't be noticeable. Good to have measured it and know.